# Excel 2010 - apply same formatting as header cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2010, if I have a header row containing 200 columns, and the first cell of each column in the first row is formatted in a different way, how do I quickly copy the formatting down to other cells in the same column?

e.g.,

```
row 1 -- F1 F2 F3 F4                 F2000
row 2 -- V1 V2 V3 V4                 V2000
row 3 -- X1 X2                       X2000
```

How do I quickly copy the formaating from F1 onto V1, X1, similarly F2 onto V2, X2...without doing that for each column?

I have drop down cell values/lists and formulae in some cells - these are not being applied if I follow the approach of 'Fill Formatting'? e.g. F1 has a formula = F2+F3; and F4 has a drop down list. How do I 'multi-apply' them 'downwards in their own column', for all 2000 columns?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the cell in row 1. Select the cells from row 2 to 2000 and do a Paste Special > Formats.

If you want to copy data validation, do a Paste Special > Validation.